# Does inotify_add_watch return watch descriptors in ascending order?

Tags: c, linux, inotify

inotify_add_watch returns an int.

I want to store the strings of the path which I am watching in an array and want to index them by the return value of inotify_add_watch.

I did a small scale test(with 10 files) and it seems to return them in an ascending order (1, 2, 3, 4...).

Is this guaranteed?

Comment: Well, [does the manual say so?](https://linux.die.net/man/2/inotify_add_watch) I don't think so, therefore don't rely on it, it's an implementation detail if it's not documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in [the documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inotify_add_watch.2.html) makes that guarantee.

In fact, this case:

> If the filesystem object was already being watched (perhaps via a different link to the same object), then the descriptor for the existing watch is returned.

seems to put the answer squarely at "no".

Would you rely on `open` returning file descriptors in ascending order? This is the same situation.

Comment: open in fact must always return the lowest available fd. This is a documented requirement and all functions allocating fds are expected to do the same. However it's largely a meaningless requirement if other code could by opening & closing fds in between/concurrently (threads, library functions, signal handlers, ...)

Comment: @R.. Great point. But yes, my point was that the sequence returned by `open` is not monotonically increasing in light of the possibility of `close` being called.